# How can I implement tree data structure offline java?

Tags: java, algorithm, offline

I want to make a tree of words and the leaf node containing index values.
I want to store this information offline , i.e i don't want the tree to be initialized at run-time rather it should be stored locally.

How am I supposed to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the indices stored locally or the structure itself? Are you referring to [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)?

Comment: Indices would be the indices of answer stored in another file eg AIML

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a **`JSON`** structure to store the tree?

You can use the [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson) to do something like this.

The only methods you would need are:

### Import:

```
public static TreeNode readJson(String file) {
    try {
        String json = null;
        json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)), "UTF-8");
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        TreeNode node = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
        return node;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Export:

```
public static void saveJson(String file, TreeNode node) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write(toJson(node));
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Okay lemme try this out and check whether is working or not